# How to create stored procedure in EF Core using .NET 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, .net-6.0

I have a class library project in .NET 6 where I am using EF Core. I am able to create tables using the code-first approach, but stuck on how to create stored procedures. I have seen a few articles on Google but it's showing using old EF 6 but not for EF Core.

Comment: Are you sure you want to *create* a stored procedure in EF? That's an odd thing to be doing. If you want to execute a pre-existing SP then you can use `FromSql()`, `FromSqlRaw()` etc

Comment: Here's a reference for you: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to create a stored procedure with EF Core, but the process to do it manually is quite simple.

First create a new migration as you would normally, it should be empty. Then edit the migration to manually create the procedure. For example:

```
public partial class MyNewStoredProcMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE PROC DoStuff....");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP PROC DoStuff");
    }
}
```

Note that you may want to move the string for the procedure into a resource file to keep things tidy.

Comment: How to read that resource file in Up() method.

Comment: You can read the file directly from disk or you can create an embedded resource, which will form part of the assembly (dll).

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in [EF Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew) with [Stored procedure mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#stored-procedure-mapping):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .InsertUsingStoredProcedure("People_Insert", builder =>
        {
            builder.HasParameter(a => a.Name);
            builder.HasResultColumn(a => a.Id);
        })
    .UpdateUsingStoredProcedure("People_Update", builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOriginalValueParameter(person => person.Id);
            builder.HasOriginalValueParameter(person => person.Name);
            builder.HasParameter(person => person.Name);
            builder.HasRowsAffectedResultColumn();
        })
    .DeleteUsingStoredProcedure("People_Delete", builder =>
        {
            builder.HasOriginalValueParameter(person => person.Id);
            builder.HasOriginalValueParameter(person => person.Name);
            builder.HasRowsAffectedResultColumn();
        });
```